# how to take the same id_following based id_follower

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I have a table of followers with a picture like the one below.

[image: Tabel Followers]

I have a code on models:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('followers','followers.id_follower = post.id_account','LEFT'); 
$id_account = $this->session->userdata('id');
$where = ("followers.id_following=$id_account or post.id_account = $id_account");
$this->db->where($where); 
$this->db->order_by('id_post','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('post', 10, $offset);
return $query->result_array();
```

My problem is the difficulty to take id_following thoroughly. Code on the above models only take `id_following` based session id. No one can help me to take `id_following` thoroughly by `id_follower` same.

Comment: Try doing this like `db->where('followers.id_following =', $id_account).or_where('post.id_account =', $id_account)` to ensure that your values are properly escaped. Putting values like `$id_account` directly in the query can be problematic.

Comment: Please always add what you are you are getting and what you are trying to get instead.

Comment: No other solution?

Comment: With your where `$this->db->where('somthing', $where);`